# Choose the student who has the highest average missing days

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the student who has the highest average missing days in returning books to the library. I have 2 tables:

- users -> id, fname, lname, professional
- loaned -> isbn(book number), id, since(date), due(date), actual(date)

Here is my method of doing this, with sub-queries

```
select concat(fname, '', lname) as name 
  from users 
 where id in ( select id 
                 from loaned 
                group by id 
               having avg(datediff(due, actual))
                      = ( select min(m) 
                            from ( select avg(datediff(due, actual)) as m 
                                     from loaned
                                    group by id 
                                          ) as minavg
                                  )
                      );
```

How could I solve this with JOINs?

Comment: apart from joins and homework, isn't your logic wrong?  the way you're doing things, if a book is returned early then it acts as a kind of "credit" that cancels out a late book.

Comment: so? Does it matter ? I need to pull out the name with the most late days. I have tried to do that we friends but we could not succeed with Join action.

Answer (score 1):

```
select concat(fname, '', lname) as name 
from users u
join loaned l on l.id = u.id and due < actual
group by 1
order by avg(actual - due) desc
limit 1
```

This query only takes the average of books that were late, not the overall average. For the over all average remove `and due < actual`

---

To return all students with a shared equal highest average:

```
select concat(fname, '', lname) as name 
from users u
join loaned l on l.id = u.id and due < actual
group by 1
having avg(actual - due) = (
    select avg(actual - due)
    from loaned
    where due < actual
    group by id
    order by 1 desc
    limit 1)
```

Comment: what does `group by 1` mean? (i know what `group by <column name>` does).

Comment: @andrewcooke it's legal (SQL standard) shorthand for "group by column number 1". Some "holier than thou" coders shun it, but I embrace its simplicity and brevity, and have never had an occasion where using it caused any negative impact of clarity or maintainability

Comment: Thanks, but your query does not answer on the situation if you have 2 names with the same amount of late days.

Comment: Well it does answer the question as stated. There is no mention of how, or even if, ties should be broken

Comment: ...but since you now raise it, see edited answer for the briefest solution I could think of to return all students with the same max average

Comment: I still don't get it(I am pretty new in this) your second query still contains "limit 1" so how is that different? will it show more than 1 result ?

Comment: That limit is for tube inner query - it gets the first row of the ordered averages, which is of course the maximum average. That value is then used in a `having` clause that filters out all but the (equal) top groups (students).